# Depth-First search in Python

Tags: python, depth-first-search

I'm trying to do a Depth-First search in Python but it's not working.

Basically we have a peg-solitaire board:

```
[1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1]
```

1's represent a peg, and 0 is an open spot.  You must move a peg one at a time TWO SLOTS backwards or forward ONLY to an empty spot. If you jump over another peg in the process it becomes an empty slot.  You do this until one peg remains. So basically, a game goes like:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1] #etc until only 1 peg left
```

Here's what I have:

```
class MiniPeg():
    def start(self):
        ''' returns the starting board '''
        board = [1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1]
        return board

    def goal(self, node):
        pegs = 0

        for pos in node:
            if pos == 1:
                pegs += 1

        return (pegs == 1) # returns True if there is only 1 peg

    def succ(self, node):
        pos = 0
        for peg in node:
            if peg == 1:                
                if pos < (len(node) - 2):  # try to go forward
                    if node[pos+2] == 0 and node[pos+1] == 1:
                        return create_new_node(node, pos, pos+2)

                if pos > 2: # try to go backwards 
                    if node[pos-2] == 0 and node[pos-1] == 1:
                        return create_new_node(node, pos, pos-2)
        pos += 1

def create_new_node(node, fr, to):
    node[fr] = 0
    node[to] = 1
    if fr > to:
        node[fr-1] = 0
    else:
        node[fr+1] = 0
    return node

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = MiniPeg()
    b = s.start()

    while not s.goal(b):
        print b
        b = s.succ(b)
```

So, now my questions:

1. Is this the right way to do a Depth-First search for this?
2. My algorithm doesn't work!!!  It gets stuck.  I've been struggling on this for days before asking here so please help.
3. Looks like I'm not following DRY, any suggestions?
4. omg help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The normal way to implement DFS in a situation where each step is a "move" from a "board position" to some possible next one, until a goal is reached, is as follows (pseudocode)

```
seenpositions = set()
currentpositions = set([startingposition])
while currentpositions:
  nextpositions = set()
  for p in currentpositions:
    seenpositions.add(p)
    succ = possiblesuccessors(p)
    for np in succ:
      if np in seenpositions: continue
      if isending(np): raise FoundSolution(np)
      nextpositions.add(np)
  currentpositions = nextpositions
raise NoSolutionExists()
```

You probably also want to keep backward links to be able to emit, at the end, the series of moves leading to the found solution (if any), but that's an ancillary problem.

I don't recognize a trace of this general structure (or reasonable variant thereof) in your code.  Why not try to record it this way?  You only need to code `possiblesuccessors` and `isending` (if you insist on keeping a position as a list you'll have to turn it into a tuple to check membership in set and add to set, but, that's pretty minor;-).

Comment: That looks good. But then you're just one step away from an A* algorithm which would converge must faster. All you need is a heuristic on the "distance left" (ie. number of moves) to the goal. Looks like this heuristic could simply be the number of pins left to flip.

Comment: Shouldn't `p` be added to `seenpositions` after adding `p`'s successors to `currentpositions`?

Comment: @jellybean, yep, I had indeed forgotten to update `seenpositions`: tx for the spotting -- editing now to fix.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that you're creating new nodes, just re-using existing ones.  DFS requires some kind of stack (either the call stack, or your own stack).  Where is that?

Comment: yea it's suppose to use a "yield" generator or something, but I was having trouble with that so I was using returns.  Can you help point in the right direction then, I'm so helplessly confused.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all a depth-first search assumes a tree. Now, that makes sense here as you have several possible moves in most cases. A depth first-search would simply try the first possible move, and then the first possible move in the new situation, and the first possible move in that new situation, until success or no more possible moves, in which case it would back up until it finds a move it hasn't tried, and go down again.

The "correct" way of doing that is with recursion. You have no recursion in your system as far as I can see.

Something like this would work (pythonic psuedo codeish english):

```
def try_next_move(self, board):
    for each of the pegs in the board:
        if the peg can be moved:
            new_board = board with the peg moved
            if new_board is solved:
                return True
            if self.try_next_move(new_board):
                return True
            # That move didn't lead to a solution. Try the next.
    # No move  worked.
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic algorithmic problem is that the `succ` function always only produces just one possible move for a given board state. Even if there would be more than one possible moves, the `succ` function just returns the first one it can find. A depth first search needs to process all possible moves in each state.

Further problems might then come from the fact that `create_new_node`, despite it's name, doesn't really create a new node, but modifies the existing one. For depth first search where you want to keep the previous node around it would be better if this function actually created a copy of the list it get's as a parameter.

Also, when checking for the possibility to go backwards in `succ`, you only try to do so if `pos > 2`. That's too restrictive, `pos > 1` would also be ok.